# Expanding specific sections of a pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table segmented by years, quarters and months. If I try to expand a quarter for 2015, however, the corresponding quarter in all other years are shown as well. How can I expand only one quarter for one year?